# Batch Moving files matching filenames to folders in C# or using a script

Tags: c#, file-io

I was wondering if someone could assist or point me in the right direction to move files where part of the filename needs to be matched to part of the foldername for example:

Moving filename Cust-10598.txt to a folder named John-Doe-10598 Is this possible?

I was able to create all the folders inside the root directory where all the files are contained, now I would like to sort them and put each of them inside the matching folder.

Any help or ideas are highly appreciated

Comment: do you have naming conventions ? when you say about part, is it always the numeric part ? will the numeric part always be at the end ?

Comment: Yes, the naming convention on the files are prefix CUST + Customer ID + File ID like this cust_xxx_xxx The folders are named like this FirstName + LastName + customer id like this firstname-lastname-id

Comment: CUST + Customer ID + File ID  => by file id, do you mean the file extension ?

Comment: sorry I put it without the file extension, it should look like this cust_custID_fileID.txt

Comment: Cust-10598.txt , so what would be fileId here ?

Comment: my bad, actual filename should be Cust-10598-153.txt

Comment: ok. Please check my answer, should work with this change as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a list of probably folders using Directory.GetDirectores(),

```
var listOfFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);
```

You can find the associated Folder for given filename using following method.

```
string GetAssociatedDirectory(string fileName,IEnumerable<string> folderNames)
{
    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"Cust-(?<Id>[\d]*)",RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Match match = regEx.Match(fileName);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var customerId = match.Groups["Id"].Value;

        if(folderNames.Any(folder=>folder.EndsWith($"-{customerId}")))
        {
            return folderNames.First(folder=>folder.EndsWith(customerId));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Folder not found");
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Invalid File Name");
}
```

You can then use File.Move to copy the file to destination directory

Comment: if(folderNames.Any(folder=>folder.EndsWith($"-{customerId}"))) So this matches the extracted ID from the file to any folder ending with the -ID right?

Comment: yes, that's right. it matches the extracted Customer Id with folder names which ends with ID

Comment: Works like a charm when passing a single filename, but I get invalid filename error when passing an array, this is what I am trying:
            string[] array = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test3");
            foreach (string name in array)
            {
                string testdir= GetAssociatedDirectory(name, listOfFolders);
                Console.WriteLine(testdir);
            }

Comment: @cadash Invalid file in custom exception thrown when encountered a file name which doesn't have a Customer ID as per the code. You might be interested to check the files to ensure all the files in the folder has Customer id in specified format

Comment: Thank you! thank you so much! I am sort of dumb with regex, how can I have it match Both the prefix Cust- and Customer- here Regex(@"Cust-(?<Id>[\d]*)" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply Split() on '-' if it's that simple of naming convention.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var file = "Cust-10598.txt";
        var fileSplit = file.Split('-');
        var sourceDir = @"C:\";
        var destFolder = "{name of destination folder}-" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileSplit[1]);
        var destPath = @"C:\newpath";

        File.Move(Path.Combine(source, file), Path.Combine(destPath, destFolder, file));
    }
}
```

Comment: The destination folders have data not present in the filename (firstname, lastname) but they have the ID. The folders look like this FirstName-LastName-ID, how can I match the ID in the file to the ID in the folder to assign it to var destFolder afterwards?